# LinkedList with 2 time data

Tags: c#

I have to give 2 time data to a linkedlist from a txt file.
but i can't fill it in.

```
StreamReader sr;
public void FileReader(string file, LinkedList<Task> Tasks)
{
    string splitter= "."; 
    int TaskIndex= 0;
    sr = new StreamReader(file);
    LinkedList<Task> data = new LinkedList<Task>();            

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string tempString = sr.ReadLine(); 
        if (splitter== tempString) 
        {
            TaskIndex++;                    
            Tasks.Add(data);

        }               
    }            
    sr.Close();            
}

public class Task
{        
    public TimeSpan FullTime= new TimeSpan(0, 24, 0, 0); 
    public TimeSpan TaskLength { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Deadline{ get; set; }
    public int Penalty{ get; } = 50000;
    public Task(TimeSpan TaskLength, TimeSpan Deadline)
    {
        this.TaskLength= TaskLength;
        this.Deadline= Deadline;
    }
}
```

And the txt: The first 2 data is the TaskLengths hour and minute the second 2 is the deadlines hour and minute, every line is a task

> 2,30,5,0.
>
> 4,0,16,0.
>
> 1,0,2,0.
>
> 6,0,14,0.
>
> 3,30,10,0.
>
> 2,0,22,0.

Comment: You're getting close votes so I think you should clarify what you mean by "but i can't fill it in".  Looking at your code and your data I'm guessing by the end of your `FileReader` method `data` is empty.  Is that correct?

Comment: data has an error: cannot convert from 'LinkedList<Task>' to 'Task'

Comment: You never create a `Task` instance and are instead adding one `LinkedList<Task>` (`data`) to another (`Tasks`).  You need to pick one list to use, either `data` or `Tasks`, and add `Task`s to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is read each line from the file, split that line on the comma character (and get rid of the period since every line is a task), parse the numbers from the line into integers, create two `TimeSpan` objects from the numbers, create a `Task` object from the two `TimeSpan` objects, and then add that `Task` to a `LinkedList<Task>`.

If that's the case, then here's a sample method that you can pass a file name to and which will return a `LinkedList<Task>` from the contents of the file:

```
public LinkedList<Task> GetTasksFromFile(string filePath)
{
    // This will hold our results from reading the file lines into Tasks
    var tasks = new LinkedList<Task>();

    // Loop through each line in the file 
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
    {
        // Split the line on the comma and period characters so we get separate values
        string[] parts = line.Split(new[] {'.', ','}, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // These will hold the parsed values from each line of text in our file
        int lengthHour;
        int lengthMinute;
        int deadlineHour;
        int deadlineMinute;

        // int.TryParse will try to convert a string to an int, and will return 
        // true if successful. It will also set the 'out' parameter to the result.
        // We do this on each part from our line of text 
        // (after ensuring that there are at least 4 parts)
        if (parts.Length > 3 &&
            int.TryParse(parts[0], out lengthHour) &&
            int.TryParse(parts[1], out lengthMinute) &&
            int.TryParse(parts[2], out deadlineHour) &&
            int.TryParse(parts[3], out deadlineMinute))
        {
            // If our parsing succeeded, create a new task
            // with the results and add it to our LinkedList
            TimeSpan length = new TimeSpan(lengthHour, lengthMinute, 0);
            TimeSpan deadline = new TimeSpan(deadlineHour, deadlineMinute, 0);
            Task task = new Task(length, deadline);
            tasks.AddLast(task);
        }
    }

    // Return our linked list back to the caller
    return tasks;
}
```